# When I should use client.available() in Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I bought an Ethernet shield and I wrote a code, but I saw that there is .available() method. I don't know where to use it. So guys, do you know where and when I should use it? Here is my sample code:

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 107);

EthernetServer server = EthernetServer(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  EthernetClient client = server.available();

  if(client) {
      if(client.available()) {
          char c = client.read();
          Serial.print(c);
      }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're using `.available()` on the server and client object already so what's the problem? Perhaps you could explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`Client.available()` returns the number of bytes that a client (remote client) may have written. If you're writing an HTTP server, the first client data would be: `GET /URL HTTP/1.0`.

You then write back to that client with `Client.write()`. For example:

```
c.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK")
```